# Get selected values from binding listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, tabcontrol

Binding ListBox inside TabControl may be a little difficult. TabControl also bound and ListBox bound in it. The header value of TabControl could be found, but the value selected in ListBox has not been retrieved since.

Main.xaml.cs

```
AddTab at = (AddTab)scenarioTC.SelectedItem;
MessageBox.Show(at.Header);
//listbox selecteditem show by Console or MessageBox

class AddTab
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<AddData> Data { get; } = new ObservableCollection<AddData>();
}

class AddData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Main.xaml

```
<TabControl x:Name="scenarioTC" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,5"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="ScenarioCB_SelectionChanged" KeyDown="ScenarioTC_KeyDown">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:AddTab">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:AddTab">
                    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" AllowDrop="True" Drop="ListBox_Drop" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Padding="0">
                        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Image x:Name ="VD" Margin="3" Source="{Binding Path}" Height="180" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <TextBlock Name="TB" Margin="3" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathod 1.Try to add Listbox SelectedIndex Property in AddTab and Binding in xaml DataTemplate.

Method 2:

```
ListBoxItem listBoxItem= scenarioTC.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(scenarioTC.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
Border border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listBoxItem,0) as Border;
ListBox listBox = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border.Child,0);
var selectedItem = listbox.SelectedItem;
```

The code were not tested but may works.

Comment: I don't know where to add the Binding of the xaml DataTemplet.